# THREE.js Using MeshPhongMaterial As Particle Material and Setting Size

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to create particles that have the properties of a Phong material (react to light), to achieve this I have used the "createMultiMaterialObject", this has worked on the most part other than ignoring the particle size, for some reason the particles seems to be weird triangle shapes, see below:

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
var ringGeometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( rad, ringSize, 1, 200, Math.PI * 2);
materials = [
p2paterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({shading: THREE.SmoothShading, blending:     THREE.AdditiveBlending, transparent: true, color: ringColour, ambient: 0x000000, specular:     0xffffff, shininess: 1, vertexColors: false  } ),
pmaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { size: 1, transparent: true,     vertexColors: true  } )
        ];
singleRing = new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(ringGeometry, materials);
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I can achieve the last bit, making the particles size 1 each - I'm so close to getting what I want that I suspect it's just an option I need to tweak somewhere.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Added a screen shot showing the issue first-hand

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( rad, ringSize, 1, 200, Math.PI * 2);

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({shading: THREE.SmoothShading, blending:     THREE.AdditiveBlending, transparent: true, color: ringColour, ambient: 0x000000, specular:     0xffffff, shininess: 1, vertexColors: false  } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { size: 1, transparent: true,     vertexColors: true  } );
var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, material );
scene.add( particles );
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question but unfortunately this yields the same result, I just end up with strange triangle shapes. I don't know if it's important but directly after I create the Torus Geometry I loop through it randomly shifting the vertices a bit, I can post this code too if it helps?

Comment: I've made a test case fiddle that exactly shows the problem with your code above: http://jsfiddle.net/AL2QN/

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with three.js, but I was messing around with your fiddle and I got something that looks more like particles by adjusting the value of RadialSegments in your TorusGeometry declaration....

```
var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 10, 10, .5, 200, Math.PI * 2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJZeH/

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately they do indeed look like particles but they don't have the Phong material which is why they are black, this means that they will be visible in all lighting conditions.

Comment: the particle systems displays sprite kind of like a billboard - i don't not think you can get a phong like material on it unless you write some custom shading.